# Libtool throws error because of path with space

Tags: c++, gmp, msys2

I'm trying to install gmp for c++ on my windows pc, but I encountered many hardships so far. I use msys2 to install gmp, which I downloaded. After "./configure" and "make", I tried to run "make check", but got

```
$ make check
make  check-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/Martin Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1'
Making check in tests
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/Users/Martin Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1/tests'
Making check in .
make[3]: Entering directory '/c/Users/Martin Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1/tests'
make  libtests.la t-bswap.exe t-constants.exe t-count_zeros.exe t-hightomask.exe t-modlinv.exe t-popc.exe t-parity.exe t-sub.exe
make[4]: Entering directory '/c/Users/Martin Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1/tests'
make[4]: 'libtests.la' is up to date.
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -no-install  -o t-bswap.exe t-bswap.o libtests.la ../libgmp.la
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for x86_64-w64-mingw32
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool:   error: cannot find the library 'Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1/libgmp.la' or unhandled argument 'Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1/libgmp.la'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:765: t-bswap.exe] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Martin Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1/tests'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1183: check-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Martin Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1/tests'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:823: check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Martin Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1/tests'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:997: check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Martin Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1'
make: *** [Makefile:1289: check] Error 2
```

Notice, that the path in the error is 'Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1/libgmp.la'. So my theory is that there is a problem because the path has a space. Could this be the origin of the error? Is there a fix or a better way for achieving what I am trying to do?

Comment: Could be very likely.

Comment: Is there a fix or should I just re-do everything in a path without a space?

Comment: The easy solution seems to be to just paths without spaces or quote the path or escape the space properly.

Comment: How do I quote the path or escape the space when all I'm doing is running "make check"?

Comment: Edit the `Makefile`(s) (or just use a path without spaces).

Comment: I edited the Makefile and replaced lines such as 
AUTOCONF = ${SHELL} "/c/Users/Martin Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1/missing" autoconf
with
AUTOCONF = ${SHELL} "/c/Users/Martin\ Clever/Desktop/Daten/C++/Privat/RecSolver/gmp-6.2.1/missing" autoconf
Still the same error
I try a path without spaces next.

Comment: Many old unix tools don't handle paths with spaces well, the usual advice is to avoid spaces in directory names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easier/less error-prone way:
Just run "pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp" with msys2 MINGW64 - No need to download the gmp library.